# How to find a 4 bytes prefix of string of bytes, which when encoded in hexadecimal in javascript

Tags: javascript, blockchain, sha256, bitcoin

Hi one of my trainer asked me to solve this mysterious question which is related to hashing, and this question is so uncommon that i'm not able to find any good source to solve and learn logic behind it.

```
Given a string of bytes, which when encoded in hexadecimal notation look like this:



f064b8b61422a3456cb273a474a1fb0cabb04200a6a82a9426bd01f56c97fbf8c4ef58634fd5cf21af29e7db3406de4f886fe71408696789f853af9932a84b79



 Find a 4-byte prefix so that, a SHA256 hash of the prefix combined with the original string of bytes, has two last bytes as 0xca, 0xfe.
```

Comment: See: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. "

Comment: You are probably thinking too complicated. It should be possible to bruteforce this in under an hour of runtime, probably actually a lot less because only the last two bytes need to match, so there will be many matches.

Comment: Well brother Yogi, This is not a homework question or i'm in school etc, actually i have been asked this question in one of the interview.

Comment: And brother i tried solving the question but failed to do so, that's why came here and asked this. So that i can have better understanding where to go so that i can get better knowledge for this sort of questions.

Comment: An attempt to solve it by yourself, would help others help you.

Comment: CherryDT yes brother i think i'm thinking too complicated.
Should i iterate the hash using sha256 library to match the last two prefixes?

Comment: Actually brothers the issue is i'm not getting the science behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried an attempt. I work with strings I'm sure it's not the most efficient. But Let's see if it works.

```js
async function sha256(message) {
  const msgBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode(message);
  const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', msgBuffer);
  const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));
  const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
  return hashHex;
}


function hexToString(hex) {
  for (var bytes = [], c = 0; c < hex.length; c += 2) {
    bytes.push(parseInt(hex.substr(c, 2), 16));
  }
  return bytes.map(function(byte) {
    return String.fromCharCode(byte)
  }).join("")
  // return bytes;
}

function hex32(val) {
  val &= 0xFFFFFFFF;
  var hex = val.toString(16).toUpperCase();
  return ("00000000" + hex).slice(-8);
}

var str = "f064b8b61422a3456cb273a474a1fb0cabb04200a6a82a9426bd01f56c97fbf8c4ef58634fd5cf21af29e7db3406de4f886fe71408696789f853af9932a84b79";


var original = hexToString(str);
var found = false;


async function search() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 0xffffffff; i++) {
    var prefix = hexToString(hex32(i))
    await sha256(prefix + original).then(function(result) {
      // console.log(result.slice(-4))
      if (result.slice(-4) == 'cafe') {
        console.log(`found a prefix: "${prefix}"`);
        found = true;
      }
    });
    if (found) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

search();
```